# Sorting Arrays for int and string

Tags: java, string, sorting

How to sort an int[] array, do i have to use this or can i just use the in built methods by java?

```
for (int x = 0; x < days.length - 1; w++) {
            for (short i = 0; i < days.length - 1; i++) {
                if (days[i].(days[i + 1]) > 0) {
                    days = days[i];

                    days[i] = days[i + 1];
                    days[i + 1] = days;


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have to write the sort yourself? What other restrictions are there? Can you, for example, use `String.compareTo`?

Comment: If my understanding is correct your issue is that you are not able to sort a string array. Is it?

Comment: yes I want to sort the string array @prashant

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a snippet to sort a simple string array. Reproduced below:

```
int length = winners.length;
        for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<length-i-1; j++){
                if(winners[j].compareTo(winners[j+1]) > 0){
                    //Swap the elements
                    String temp = winners[j];
                    winners[j] = winners[j+1];
                    winners[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(String winner: winners){
            System.out.println(winner);
        }
```

This is working correctly.
If you want to ignore case you can use compareToIgnoreCase method.

Comment: how would i do i sort a short[] array. It has year values and i want it to sort in ascending order. @prashant

Comment: i do that^ and it wont go through, it says cannot invoke compareTo(short) on the primitive type short.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to sort arrays is with `Arrays.sort`:

```
    String[] array = {"c", "a", "b"};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    output -> [a, b, c]

    String[] array = {"2", "1", "3"};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    output -> [1, 2, 3]
```

The same process will work for an array of `ints` (or any primitive) too